# Does node_delete() function deletes the attached media files as well?

Tags: 7, nodes, database, media

I'm deleting my `'articles'` created before `Sat Nov 1 00:00:00 2014 GMT` from `Drupal 7.34` site, but I'm not sure whether the `node_delete()` delete the media files as well?

Below is my processing code:

```
<?php

// Fetch the NIDs of 'articles' created before Sat Nov 1 00:00:00 2014 GMT
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid'))
->condition('type', 'article')
->condition('created', 1414800000, '<') // 1414800000 = Sat Nov 1 00:00:00 2014 GMT
->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
->range(0, 100);
$result = $query->execute();

// Code to delete my articles in bulk
while ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  $nid = $record['nid'];
  echo $nid;
  node_delete($nid);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If the file has no references left to it in the `file_usage` table, then yes, it will be deleted.

If there are remaining references, it won't be deleted.

Either way, `file_delete()` is definitely invoked for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [node_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7) function delete all the media files as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know [node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) does it all for you ,, it removes associated fields and everything ..

Answer (score 0):

You are right **node_delete()** will delete all associated files uploaded in the file system and in **managed_files** table and all entries related to that node id you pass.